# Blurred fonts - Monitor NEC EA274WMi - MacBook Pro retina 13 - Yosemite

Tags: display

my new monitor NEC EA274WMi looks sharp when connected to windows but blurred all font texts once connected to OS X. It's very annoying, I work with user interface, small texts, labels, icons.

I tried all every cables and adaptors: display miniport, DVI-D and HDMI. Same problem.

Other monitors with the same issue have solved forcing RGB mode instead of YCbCr, but this patch haven't worked for me http://embdev.net/topic/284710

Is there someone with the same NEC monitor that have resolved (or haven't) this issue?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Ste

This is my configuration: 
Monitor NEC EA274WMi, MacBook Pro Retina, 13 inch, late 2012, Intel HD Graphics 4000 1024 MB, OS X Yosemite 10.10.3

This is a screenshot from my desktop, can you see how blurred is the number 1 in the red square aside the stack exchange logo?

[image: blurred]

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling LCD font smoothing. Go to the Apple menu, choose System Preferences, then choose General. It's the last checkbox at the very bottom.

[image: Screenshot of OS X General preference pane in System Preferences with LCD font smoothing circled]

Answer (score 0):

Recently I had a similar problem with mail. Reducing transparency under "Accessibility" in System Preferences solved it for me. It seems to be a bug with font rendering.

Comment: Already tried this too without success, thanks Awado.